# Ввод даты только с помощью календаря

Tags: html

Есть вот такой кусок кода:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" id="birthday" name="birthday" placeholder="Пример: 13.03.1993" max="31-12-9999" required/>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы с помощью клавиатуры туда ничего нельзя было вписать, а значение попадало только с помощью всплывающего календаря?

Comment: onfocus="(this.type='date')" - вызывает у меня календарь. 
Если же просто выбрать тип date вместо text, тогда placeholder перестает отображаться

Comment: Так добавьте ещё одно событие `onChange`, которое будет блокировать любой ввод данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавите `onkeydown="return false"`

```
<input onkeydown="return false" class="form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" id="birthday" name="birthday" placeholder="Пример: 13.03.1993" max="31-12-9999" required/>
```